# calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix} \, dx}{x^3-3ix^2+2x+2i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I guess that i could start by equating the denominator to $0$ solving it for roots.
$$x^3-3ix^2+2x+2i=0$$
$$x(x^2-3ix+2)=-2i$$ 
But i have no idea how to continue calculating this integral. It will be great if someone could explain how to continue this question and a guide in solving complex integrals as such.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no typo? The integral would be much easier to compute if the denominator was $x^3-3ix^2+2x-2i$.

Comment: the result is very big!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No that was the required integral

Comment: $\pi  e^{\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3+3 \text{$\#$1}^2-2 \text{$\#$1}+2\&,1\right]} \text{Root}\left[13924 \text{$\#$1}^6-3540 \text{$\#$1}^4+225 \text{$\#$1}^2+4\&,3\right]$